# ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d minimum bar width

Tags: ngx-charts

I would like to set the width of the bars to be a minimum of 12px. I would actually prefer to have a fixed width on the bars period.

As an example, when I am displaying 10 days of data, the graph looks fine, but for 30 days, it does not look good at all. Any thoughts on making this look better?

I added a horizontal scroll, but the width of the bars is automatically calculated based on the number of items in the graph, irrespective of the graph width. Is there any way to alter this behavior?

Screen capture: https://share.getcloudapp.com/yAubDN8X

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `[barPadding]="1"` to `ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d` element

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d [barPadding]="1" ...>...</ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [groupPadding]="1" to ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d element

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d [groupPadding]="1" ...>...</ngx-charts-bar-vertical-2d>
```

as long as you minimize the padding between groups, the barWidth with grow automatically !

Comment: this helps a little, but the bars are still fairly narrow while there are still lots of white space all around the groups.

Answer (score 0):

You should bring only the data that you can see on the screen. Use array.splice(limitIndex, limitIndex + 10) then in your horizontal scroll if you have arrows (buttons) you can increment or decrement the value of limitIndex and bring the data again.